# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused E/flutter (12270):

Tags: android, flutter, runtime-error

[This is log printed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcaC2.png)

Future apicall() async {
http.Response response;

```
// response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users/1'));
response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse('http://localhost:1337/api/registrations?populate=*'));

print(response.statusCode);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  setState(() {
    // stringResponse = response.body;

    mapResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    print(mapResponse);
  });
}
```

}